# Is there a specific order for inserting dimms in a server motherboard?

Tags: memory, cpu, motherboard, xeon

So I just got an [Intel S5400SF server board](http://ark.intel.com/products/29871/Intel-Server-Board-S5400SF) and I have 8 sticks of 2gb RAM. I was wondering since there are 16 slots, is there a specific order which I should insert the slots in? I know that with normal consumer motherboards you normally skip every other one if you are only filling half of the slots. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the service guide, there are at minimum 4 slots that do have to be filled before all others

> The initial four DIMMs installed must be populated in the blue slots: DIMM A1, DIMM B1, DIMM C1, and DIMM D1.

<sup>[source (page 26)](http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/server/s5400sf/sb/sr1560sf_serviceguide.pdf)</sup>

I'd continue that pattern with A2,B2,C2,D2,A3 etc as it seems that this is trying to split the RAM among all available channels.